# using array_walk on multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [keyword] => nothing [id] => 44 ) [1] => Array ( [keyword] => everything [id] => 45 ) [2] => Array ( [keyword] => dogs [id] => 46 ) )
```

I basically want to create a link like this:

```
<a href="mypage.php?pid=ID">KEYWORD</a>
```

So I was thinking about using array_walk, but I dont think this will work on a multidimensional array, how do I go about getting it to iterate through my array and output the ID and keyword for each one of my entries in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `foreach` loop:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        "keyword" => "anything",
        "id"      => 44
    ),
    array(
        "keyword" => "everything",
        "id"      => 45
    ),
    array(
        "keyword" => "dogs",
        "id"      => 46
    ),
);

foreach ($array as $link) {
    $keyword = $link["keyword"];
    $id      = $link["id"];
    echo "<a href='mypage.php?pid=$id'>$keyword</a>" . PHP_EOL;
}
```